# ASP.NET Core MVC--getting error when adding new 'Razor View - Empty"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with the latest release of the Core framework. I am creating a new Core MVC app against the Core Framework version 3.1. I have a controller and an action method. I want to create a new view. I am 'Empty' Razor View scaffolded item option. However, I get an error message as follows:

Files and Folders Cannot be

- Empty Strings
- System reserved names, including 'CON, 'AUX', 'PRN', 'COM1', or 'LPT2'
- contain only '.'
- have any of the following characters / ? : & \ | # %

[image: Visual Studio Error Message when creating Empty View]

The error occurs when selecting the option to add the view and before I ever get the dialogue box asking for the view's name.

Any ideas why I am getting this message?

Comment: 'The error occurs when selecting the option to add the view'?   Which option you select? Where is the Option you mentioned?

Comment: @m.r226 When I click 'add view' I get a dialogue window presenting two options: the first is 'Razor View - Empty' and the other is 'Razor View.' I am trying to create an empty view.

Comment: Any luck on this one? As I get the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.  After some investigation I realized that my project folder path had a '#' in it (option 4 in the list of errors above).  I created the project with a new folder path (e.g. in the c:/somepath/repos folder), which solved the error.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I had my project in the directory containing # in the path. Moving the project to new directory solved the issue. :)